# JWT and antiforgery token

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt

I have been researching about JWT and antiforgery token and I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-based-authentication) article from Microsoft where it indicates that in JWT the antiforgery validation is not necessary.

Is this correct or did I understand wrong?

I am developing an application with webapi and angular 6 with JWT

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Antiforgery token protects from CSRF attacks, which are based on cookies.

As long as your JWT is **manually** attached to the selected requests (unlike cookies that are attached to every request in the browser) the CSRF is not possible anymore.

So, the answer is: it is correct for the tokens that are not sent in cookies.

Comment: It's what I thought I understood, thanks for your response

Comment: however you will make yourself more vulnerable to XSS since javascript now has access to your token. Better to store it in httponly cookie and then fix the csrf since that is trivial compared to fixing the other stuff.

Comment: @smnbbrv What if your'e attaching the JWT to a header for each request after authentication? (Session)

Comment: Would like to say thank you for a very simple answer. You explained a complex topic in few sentences that's easily understandable. Thank you!